# Inserting Pages into document but don't want them numbered or included in page count

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm using Word 2010. I need to insert some pages into my document but don't want them counted. I have a contents page but I don't want these pages included in the count for the contents. It there a trick to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a section break to the end of the page you want to skip and while in the header, in the ribbon choose `Page Number` -> `Format Page Numbers` and set the page numbering to start at the appropriate value so it doesn't include the previous page.